# Usar value, para otro value dentro del mismo Object. Angular/ionic/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic, objeto, javascript-objeto

Hola comunidad nuevamente tengo una duda que no puedo solucionar.
tengo este objeto dentro de mi component environment.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  api: {
    baseUrlApi: 'https://demo.io/',
    baseUrlImages: 'https://demo-api/upload/',
    baseUrlApiAr: 'https://demo-api/',
    baseUrlApiMx: 'https://api/',
    baseUrlImagesAr : **`${environment.api.baseUrlApi}/upload/`**,
    baseUrlImagesMx: 'https://api-mx.hemoder.io/upload/',
    client_id:'aaaaa',
    client_secret: 'aaa',
  },
}
```

bueno, la idea es que en **baseUrlImagesAr** utilice el valor de **baseUrlApiAr** y agregarle el upload, con template strings no funciona, ya que me dice que tengo un error de block-scope. No se como solucionarlo!!

Muchas gracias por su ayuda!!

Comment: porque no defines `baseUrlApiAr` como una variable antes y la usas para setear el valor de `baseUrlApiAr` y de `baseUrlImagesAr` dentro del objeto que exportas?

Comment: Ok, lo probe y funciona, lo que si, no se si es buena practica, lo es? esta bien declarar la variable fuera del export? gracias genio abrazo!!

Comment: Si, es totalmente válido. Te lo puse como respuesta, considera marcarla como aceptada para asi ayudar a toda la comunidad

Comment: Groso! gracias un abrazo, sirvio de 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

porque no defines `baseUrlApiAr` como una variable antes y la usas para setear el valor de `baseUrlApiAr` y de `baseUrlImagesAr` dentro del objeto que exportas:

Asi:

```
const baseUrlApiAr = "https://demo-api/'";

export const environment = {
  production: false,
  api: {
    baseUrlApi: 'https://demo.io/',
    baseUrlImages: 'https://demo-api/upload/',
    baseUrlApiAr: baseUrlApiAr,
    baseUrlApiMx: 'https://api/',
    baseUrlImagesAr : `${baseUrlApiAr}/upload/`,
    baseUrlImagesMx: 'https://api-mx.hemoder.io/upload/',
    client_id:'aaaaa',
    client_secret: 'aaa',
  },
}
```